# Nested Components Event Handling in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is my sample code

```
..


 render(){
        return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.EventHandler.bind(this)}>
         <Text>....</Text>
         .....
         <WebView source={{html: this.state.htmlContent}}
                  onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationChange.bind(this)}>
         </WebView>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
           ....
  onNavigationChange(event) {
     if (!event.url.startsWith("about:blank")) {
        Linking.openURL(event.url).catch(err => console.log('An error occurred', err));
        }
    }

        ....
```

My this.state.htmlContent contains URL's. The above code, fires the 'Linking.openURL' API correctly in 'onNavigationChange' however also fires the 'EventHandler' function. I would like the 'EventHandler' not to be fired if the user clicked on a URL. If the user did not click on the URL and clicked on anywhere else in the WebView or the components above the WebView, I would like 'EventHandler' to fire.

Comment: stop the propagation of event, use this line in `onNavigationChange` method in the last : `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: I had tried that before but I get the exception event.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function. I am using RN 0.39.